# How to append each column of file1 to a specific field of file2 and make a new output file?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk

I want to append each column of file 1 as the 4th column of file 2 and export as a new file with the column number from file 1 or something similar as the output name.

Input File 1 and 2 have the same number of rows:

Input File 1 has N columns:

```
12 23 34  .....
33 34 23
67 09 34
45 67 34
65 76 44
64 33 96
```

Input File 2 originally has 5 columns

```
AA BB FF DD 6
AA CC HH NN 7
AA DD II RR 4
AA EE JJ PP 2
AA FF KK QQ 9
AA GG LL SS 8
```

For example, the first 3 output files would look like this:

Output File 1 (column 1):

```
AA BB FF 12 DD 6
AA CC HH 33 NN 7
AA DD II 67 RR 4
AA EE JJ 45 PP 2
AA FF KK 65 QQ 9
AA GG LL 64 SS 8
```

Output File 2 (column 2):

```
AA BB FF 23 DD 6
AA CC HH 34 NN 7
AA DD II 09 RR 4
AA EE JJ 67 PP 2
AA FF KK 76 QQ 9
AA GG LL 33 SS 8
```

Output File 3 (column 3):

```
AA BB FF 34 DD 6
AA CC HH 23 NN 7
AA DD II 34 RR 4
AA EE JJ 34 PP 2
AA FF KK 44 QQ 9
AA GG LL 96 SS 8
```

The new file names can be file1, file2, file3...or column1, column2, column3....or something similar. How can I achieve this please? (for loop, awk, paste, etc.)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Most tools like "awk" and "sed" are used like "pipes": INPUT => PROCESSING => OUTPUT.  The problem is that you've got *multiple* streams you want to process on a per-line basis.  Frankly, I'd use something like Perl or Python (or even C), then just open two files.  IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I've heard people were using python to do the same formatting thing. Since I'm very new to python, could you give me an example on the above question please?

Comment: @paulsm4: it doesn't matter to awk if it's input is coming from a pipe or a file and it can handle multiple files with or without a pipe just fine. `cat file1 | awk '{print}' - file2 file3` for example would print the contents of all 3 files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your columns are tab-separated, you can easily profit from `cut` and `paste`:

```
for i in {1..N} ; do  # Insert the real N here, or change to $(seq 1 $N)
    cut -f1-3 input2 | \
        paste - \
              <(cut -f$i input1) \
              <(cut -f4- input2) \
        > output$i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This method processes each file only once, which is a help if the files are large. It does, however, require the first file to be stored in memory:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {n=NF} 
    NR==FNR {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
            file1[i, FNR]=$i
        next
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            filename = "merged" i
            print $1, $2, $3, file1[i, FNR], $4, $5 >> filename
        }
    }
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is all you need:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { hd=$1" "$2" "$3"; tl=$4" "$5; next }
{  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      print hd, $i, tl > "file" i
   }
}
' file2 file1
```

Comment: this doesn't work. did you mean `hd[FNR]` and `tl[FNR]` ?

Comment: I definitely didn't mean that since hd and tl aren't arrays but this answer is from 2012 so I'm not going to revisit it now 6 years later.